# How can I manipulate Winforms chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a problem fitting my chart:

[image: Bar Chart]

How can I adjust or manipulate the y-axis numbers to start from where I want it?

Secondly, is there a way (properties) which may help me display this graph friendly? As we can see all x-axis name aren't displayed and maybe a space b/w grey and blue bars?

Any help to how to display charts friendly is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Interval` of each Axis:

```
yourChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 17;
```

And you can make it start at any `Offset`:

```
yourChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalOffset = 11;
```

As for the `X-Axis Labels` it is hard to tell without knowing your code..

..but basically the same options apply here too:

```
yourChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

To control the widths of the columns you set their custom property `PixelPointWidth`  but adding a gap is not possible.

All solutions I found are hacks and the best one is to add a dummy `Series` between the real data series:

```
chart1.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = "33";
chart1.Series["gap"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "33";
chart1.Series[2]["PixelPointWidth"] = "33";
```

Fill it with the same number of `DataPoints` with an X-Value of 0!

[image]